# jQuery Children Before syntax issue

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm pulling in an XML document through AJAX and trying to insert a new node at the top of the document, but I'm getting a new node inserted above EVERY matching child node. I had thought that by using `.children(0)` I would only do this once.

What is my error?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: fileUrl,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseResultsXML
});
function parseResultsXML(xml) {
  $(xml).children(0).children(0).before("<item>New Node</item> \n");
  var xmlOutput = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);
  console.log(newfile, xmlOutput);
}
```

.

```
//Original File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>Existing Node 1</item>
    <item>Existing Node 2</item>
</items>

//Expected Output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>New Node</item>
    <item>Existing Node 1</item>
    <item>Existing Node 2</item>
</items>

//Actual Output
<items>
    <item>New Node</item>
    <item>Existing Node 1</item>
    <item>New Node</item>
    <item>Existing Node 2</item>
</items>
```

Comment: [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) optionally accepts selector as parameter, but not index. Use `.children(':first')` or `.children().eq(0)`.

Comment: .eq(0) did the trick. Want to submit the answer?

Comment: If you think that it should be answer - then yes :)

Answer (score 1):

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) optionally accepts [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) as parameter, but not an index.
You can use `.children(':first')` or `.children().eq(0)`.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/kLrtbg2b/1/).

```
<div>
    <span>first</span>
    <span>second</span>
</div>

console.log($('div').children().eq(0).text());
console.log($('div').children(':first').text());
```